# Case-insensitive Query

Tags: jpa, case-insensitive

I have some ticket numbers that may have numbers and letters mixed. I'll be passing in the `ticketNumberIds` into this method (user input) and I want it to query against the Oracle database and have the query pick up tickets that differ by upper and lower cases.

How do I make the following a case-insensitive query?

```
public List<TicketDO> getTicketDOsById(final List<String> ticketNumberIds) {

    String myQuery = "from TicketDO t where t.ticketNumberId in (:ticketNumberIds)";

    return getEntityManager().createQuery(myQuery).setParameter("ticketNumberIds", ticketNumberIds)
    .getResultList();

}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use UPPER to perform case insensitive queries.

```
public List<TicketDO> getTicketDOsById(final List<String> ticketNumberIds) {

    String myQuery = "from TicketDO t where UPPER(t.ticketNumberId) in (:ticketNumberIds)";
    List<String> upperNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String number : ticketNumberIds) {
        upperNumbers.add(number.toUppercase());
    }
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(myQuery).setParameter("ticketNumberIds", upperNumbers)
    .getResultList();

}
```

Comment: This is not working for me, I'm running on a Derby database. Could this be due to some type of dialect discrepancy?

Comment: I am using Derby too and it works just fine. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Note that this will likely force a Table Scan in the DB, so if you have an index on ticketNumberId, it likely won't be used. To avoid this problem you could convert to uppercase in your entity setter, so that all ticket numbers are stored in Upper case during .persist(). Then function UPPER() is no longer required in the code above and hence any index on that column remains usable.